# How can I minimize the top and bottom "padding" for HTML table cells?

Tags: html, css, html-table, cellpadding

I try to render a table with as litte text cell padding above and below as possible.

The snippet below shows what I have done so far. However it still contains visible top and bottom "padding" for the cell text.

What other CSS options exist to reduce this white space above the text, so that the text is rendered just below the top line, and the bottom line is drawn just below the text without a gap?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  line-height: 1;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Table Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        First row
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Second row
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Many thanks for the answers so far!

In my case, the actual font families and font sizes are unknown, this means that the CSS can't use any fixed values for line height as this has the risk of cut-off characters. So I am looking for a 'canonical' and safe solution.

Ideally, there is just one single CSS setting which causes the 'gap' between text and border to disappear, and works with all fonts families and font sizes (there might be more than one font used in a single cell).

Comment: changing the line-height on the text might help

Comment: padding:0 to td?

Comment: @AndreF yes, this has a small effect. However there is still a visible padding left

Comment: Don't use a `p` within your `td`...Unless you *really* mean you have a paragraph of text. See [Is it good to put `<p>` inside `<td>` to put content text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1944213/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I removed the p (makes the example more readable)

Answer (score 1):

first make the cell font family same, here you are describing only one cell font family, that's why both cells have different line height and padding.

so make it one font family && make line height 12px;

Comment: Many thanks, please see my edit - font families and font sizes are unknown so there is the danger that fixed values for line height cause cut-off characters.

Comment: ok use  this way  
td {
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

so no more padding and margin, basically you need to specify the line-height in pixels

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body,
p {
  margin: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

It minimizes even more the margin and the padding in the cell.

Comment: With Firefox and Chrome, I see no difference. Which browser do you use for testing?

Comment: I'm using Chrome v74.0.3729.169 and I can see a bit of a difference.

Comment: Same version here, I am not sure what is wrong with my browser. I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to add a div on each row to margin-bottom them ?

Like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Table Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
   <div class="FirstRow">
          First row
   </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <div class="SecondRow">
          Second row
          </div>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

and

```
body,
p {
  margin: 0px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

 .FirstRow {
  margin-bottom: ...px;
}

 .SecondRow {
  margn-bottom: ...px;
}

 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

?

Comment: How would adding more elements to the HTML reduce the amount of space? Please [edit] your question to explain how this answers the OP's problem.

Comment: Hello, i added <Div> element into html to edit them into css. And then add a margin-top: ...px; to reduce the padding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
td {
  line-height: 10px; /* or value which suits your design */
}
```

How about this?:

```
td div{
    margin-top: -4px; /* or value which suits your design */
}

....
<td><div>Your Data</div></td>
....
```

Comment: line-height: 1; (unitless) is the recommended way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height - I don't have control over the actual font sizes so I can't use a fixed value

Comment: "Try this" is rarely a good answer. Better to explain why you are suggesting the code present in the answer.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey , property line-height controls the space between lines of text. As we know that, by default TD get automatically resized according to its child contents. So forcing it to reduce the line space might do the trick.

Comment: [Edit] your question with the explanation so the OP and future visitors know that.

Comment: In case of <div> css property margin-top accepts negative values also, so similarly you can push the div to pass through / overlap the default margin.

Answer (score 0):

the cell itself also give padding.So please give "padding:0" and "line-height:.9em"(90% of font-size).

```
td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding:0;
  line-height:.9em;
}
```

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  vertical-align:top;
  line-height:.9em;
padding:0;

}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid;
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          First row
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          Second row jygq
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "Try this" is rarely a good answer. Better to explain why you are suggesting the code present in the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I have added JSFiddle link

Comment: Adding a JSFiddle link was orthogonal what I was saying :). You should explain how your code solves the OP's problem. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) instead of JSFiddle if you want to provide a runnable example.

Comment: The cell itself also give padding. So reset it to zero and reduce line-height to .9em(90% of font-size)

Comment: [Edit] your question with the explanation so the OP and future visitors know that.

Comment: I m using stack overflow for the first time. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: No worries! I just want to make sure your answer is the best it can be :).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have added Stack Snippets. :)

Comment: Many thanks, however with line-height 0.9, some characters might get cut off - maybe there is a "safer" solution

Comment: @mjn please see the snippet

Comment: Many thanks, please see my edit - font families and font sizes are unknown beforehand so there is the danger that fixed values for line height cause cut-off characters. Also there may be more than one font used in a cell.

Comment: Also you need to set the padding 0 to the Cell @mjn

Comment: Please note the line-height value is in em - @mjn